# White space issue on right of web page

Tags: css

I have been trying to determine the cause of the following issue on a web page.

With the code below, when any browser is resized and the page becomes horizontally scrollable, a white space appears on the right.

How can I remove this white space? Thanks for all help given!

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrap {
  background-color: #2a2c67;
}
.main {
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1300px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="main">Content Goes Here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

the container "wrap" has no width set so, as a block element it will take 100% of the ACTUAL window size. when you horizontal scroll because the child has a fixed width bigger than his parent and the actual window, you will scroll the child, but the parent will remain with whatever window size it's atm and scrolling out of the window. It won't dinamically change his current width (as browsers understand) to fill the child width.

Imo you just have to change the background color to the children to fix it (not that it's broken).

Edited: Or as other people said... set the width to the wrap and not to the "main"

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrap {
  
}
.main {
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1300px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #2a2c67;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="main">Content Goes Here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate your explanation. Any thoughts on how I can get the blue to stretch the entire screen, even when resized etc?  Maybe there is a better way for me to achieve this structurally? i was trying to get the inner box to have a set width of 1300px, while the outer box stretches the limit of the page.

Comment: check my updated "code snippet". In the example code I has just changed the background colour to the child insteed of the parent, But I have no idea if this can be done in your full project. The sugerences in the other comments are also right. set the fixed witdth to the parent insteed of the children. (children just set it to width 100%)

Comment: Just take into account that when you use width 100% (or you just don't set any width  fixed value in a block element), browsers will always understand the element has a width of 100% px of the current window  (and any children fixed witdh wider than the window won't change it)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I believe I have a fix!